# How to correctly implement Tooltip in Angular 9 with Ng-Bootstrap 6

Tags: ng-bootstrap, angular9

Trying to implement Tooltip in Angular 9 app with Ng-Bootstrap.  I imported NgbModule in app.module, but no tooltips wouldn't display at all.  app.module code:

```
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    NgbModule,
    SharedComponentsModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(){}
}
```

I got Tooltip to work, but I had to import `NgbModule` in the component's parent module (SharedComponentsModule) and import `NgbTooltip` in the component itself (in addition to importing NgbModule in app.module) - didn't think these steps were necessary.

SharedComponentsModule code:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { SharedComponentsRoutingModule } from './shared-components-routing.module';
import { searchComponent } from './search/search.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    searchComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    NgbModule,
    SharedComponentsRoutingModule
  ],
  exports: [
  ]
})
export class SharedComponentsModule { }
```

searchComponents code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbTooltip } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
```

searchComponents.html code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary mr-2" placement="left" ngbTooltip="Tooltip on left">Tooltip on left</button>
```

index.html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Search App</title>
      <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 shrink-to-fit=yes">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/coliff/bootstrap-rfs/bootstrap-rfs.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/************.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=*********************************"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Question - is it necessary to import NgbModule in the parent module (in addition to app.module) of the component in which NgbModule is being used and import NgbTooltip (or any other Ng-Bootstrap component for that matter) in the component where the Ng-Bootstrap component is being used for it to work?  Ng-Bootstrap documentation doesn't suggest doing this, but it's the only way I'm able to make it work.  So any clues on what I might be doing incorrectly or any other settings I should tweak to avoid the unnecessary importing?

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not necessary to import `NgbModule` to have the tooltips working.

As it is mentionned [in the documentation](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started#imports) :

> Instead of importing the whole library with NgbModule, you could only
>   import modules with components you need, ex. pagination and alert.
>
> The resulting bundle will be smaller in this case.

Your problem is that you try to import `NgbTooltip`, and you should import the module   `NgbTooltipModule` instead :

```
import { NgbTooltipModule } from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";

@NgModule({
  imports: [NgbTooltipModule],
})
```

That's it, everything should work now.